# finding period using fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

In the plot squared length of Fourier coefficients vs frequency, the peak gives the strongest frequency. does it give the accurate value of period??
Is it like a single frequency in frequency domain corresponds to a range of periods??

Comment: This is a question in signal processing.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, do you mean it is not a question in computer science?

Comment: @usul I'd say it's electrical engineering, though signal processing is definitely used by people working in CS departments.